# How to identify legacy API usage?

Tags: api, soap-api

We're trying to sort out a situation where we know that an org is calling a legacy API version (v19) that will be retired, but we don't know where the calls are coming from.

We used the Salesforce guidance (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000351312&type=1 and https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/08/make-api-version-retirements-a-no-op) to check the ApiTotalUsage EventLogFile. This identified some legacy calls where we have the user name, timestamp, version, and API family (SOAP). It has no value for the Client Name.

I tried correlating the timestamps and users against the Login History, but nothing matches up. And API version is recorded there - none of the logins are using an old API.

So, I figured that the API calls could be via OAuth. The OAuth tokens for the users in the event log didn't contain anything suspicious. In fact, one user had no OAuth tokens.

So, I wondered if it might be from a Visualforce page using remoting, the AJAX toolkit, or jsforce. Searching the unpackaged code found nothing. I guess it could be hidden away in a managed package code?

Are there other places to continue this investigation?

Comment: Have you used sfdx to pull all the metadata to make it easy to search, using CLI tools on your local machine, including look for named credentials?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see - it's an external org calling a legacy API on your target org?

Comment: Hi Phil - good suggestion. That's exactly what I did when I said that I searched the unpackaged code. We were already doing CI, so I cloned the repo and searched in Illuminated Cloud. Given that I found nothing, I'm thinking that it must be external, or a managed package. Some of those packages were installed in 2012 and never updated! But I can't think of an easy way to be sure

Comment: Could you enable debug logs against the contextual user (of the API call) to gain more info?

Comment: We are having the same issue. Were you able to find out where the calls were coming from? We can see one call in our prod org but we can't find out where it is coming from.

Comment: The best I could do was to enable debug logs on the users mentioned in the event log. Then correlate timestamps between the event log and debug log to try to get some insight. That has helped a bit, but still not clarified everything