How can I identify which connections or connected apps are using legacy API versions?
I have received an alert from Salesforce stating I'm using a legacy version of REST / SOAP in my org. Is there I can identify which app / service is using an older version?
I have tried following the instructions on this help page, but running the SOQL query in my environment returns no results.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/367557/how-to-identify-legacy-api-usage

@identigral I used this post first, which also links to the same help article. I am having an issue where nothing is returned in the query mentioned.

That help article is mostly useless because EventLogFile functionality is only available in the Event Monitoring paid add-on.  Salesforce always fails to clarify that painful fact.
Thus the only information that you can actually access is in the LoginHistory object, but that will only give you the username and API version, not what package / Apex class is being used.
You may just have to review all your Apex classes and check with all the vendors of your installed packages to what API versions they use.
